# How to use a ListView or other technique to show complex messages?

Tags: android, android-studio

I started learning Android about one week ago. I've completed 15% of a book I read some of the docs. I've seen View, Viewgroup (layouts), the hierarchy of layout elements, some widgets like EditText and others. I am getting borred, I want to do something that assembles my knowledge until now. But there's something in the way that I didn't study yet. I want to use a ListView to display a chat like user interface so I can practice what I've learning related to layouts. The problem is that the ArrayAdapter is too limitated, it show only a string. In a chat there's other information like the indication whether the user has seen the message, whether the message is from me or from the other person that was talking to. Like this:

```
Mensagem from other 1
 vista                        minha mensagem

Mensagem from other 2
 não vista

                              Minha mensagem
```

Which is the easiest way to have a functionality that would be like "having a ListView that accepts an object and I can process the various properties of this object to make highly customizable view based on each data entry".

Comment: not sure how to accomplish this with a `ListView`, though it's much easier with a `RecyclerView`... it displays a list of customizable objects with a custom layout for its items

you could read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) or see [this](https://encrypted-vtbn2.gstatic.com/video?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZUwnYmGOpz3Ra8DoqUm0hYMy_htDfIv5srE3XBuc8FROFvWvC) video about `RecyclerView`

Comment: The easiest way is to write a custom adapter (which can extend BaseAdapter). The main reason that ListView is rarely used today is that RecyclerView has a better performance (AFAIK it was invented to address the shortcomings of Listview).

Comment: The way to go is with RecyclerView. Thanks for the tip. I am liking Android developement. Things are very concise and intuitive. I hope that things keep like this until the end of my studying.